# Conexão WebRequest

Tags: c#, html

Eu tenho um site pronto, mas quero que o meu programa verifique o login do usuário no site.
Basicamente ele pode se cadastrar em ambos e acessar ambos com o mesmo usuário(O site e o sistema usa o mesmo banco de dados). Mas não estou conseguindo fazer essa verificação pelo sistema.

```html
   <?php include "./config/global.php";
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
if(isset($_SESSION['login23'])){
echo '<script>location.href="principal.php";</script>';
}
?>
<?php include "php/head.php";?>
<title>Entrar - <?php echo $titulocf;?></title>
<style type="css">
.text-transform: lowercase;
</style>
<audio src="" autoplay></audio>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" id="validate" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" role="form">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enviar_cadastro']) && $_POST['enviar_cadastro'] == 'envia'){
?>
<div style="display:none;">
</div>
<?php
$login = $_POST['login'];
$login = antiSQL($login);
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$senha = antiSQL($senha);
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE login='$login' AND senha='$senha' AND suspenso='nao'";
$query1 = mysql_query($query1);
$total1 = mysql_num_rows($query1);

$select = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE login='$login'";
                        $result = mysql_query($select);
                        while($l = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         $suspenso = $l['suspenso'];
      }
if($total1 == "1"){

$_SESSION['login23'] = $login;
$login23 = $_SESSION['login23'];
$log = "Usuario entrou no Painel de Controle !";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$hora = date("h:i:s");
$data = date("d/m/Y");
$genero = "entrou";
$registro = "$data ás $hora";
$insert = "INSERT INTO log (log, ip, data, autor, genero) VALUES ('$log', '$ip', '$registro', '$login', '$genero')";
$resultado = mysql_query($insert) or die ("");

echo '<script language= "JavaScript">location.href="principal.php"</script>';

}if($total1 == "0"){
$login_error="<b>Login</b>, ou <b>Senha</b> incorretos !";
}

}?>
<div class="login-container animated fadeInDown">
    <div class="loginbox bg-white">
        <div class="loginbox-title"><span class="text-info">MM</span><span>onitor</span>
</div>
        <div class="loginbox-social">
            <div class="social-title ">Entre na sua conta</div>
        </div>
        <div class="loginbox-or">
            <div class="or-line"></div>
        </div>
  <?php if(isset($login_error)){ 
   
   if ($suspenso == "sim") {
echo '<div class="alert alert-danger fade in radius-bordered alert-shadowed">
                                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                                            ×
                                        </button>
                                        <i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i>
                                        <strong>Erro</strong> Hotel suspenso.
                                    </div>';
}
  elseif (empty($login)) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-danger fade in radius-bordered alert-shadowed">
                                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                                            ×
                                        </button>
                                        <i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i>
                                        <strong>Erro</strong> Informe um usuário e senha.
                                    </div>';
}else{
echo '<div class="alert alert-danger fade in radius-bordered alert-shadowed">
                                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                                            ×
                                        </button>
                                        <i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i>
                                        <strong>Erro</strong> Usuário ou senha incorretos.
                                    </div>';
}
 } ?>
        <div class="loginbox-textbox">
            <input type="text" name="login" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuário" />
        </div>
        <div class="loginbox-textbox">
            <input type="password" name="senha" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" />
        </div>
        <div class="loginbox-forgot">
            <a href="senha.php">Esqueçeu sua senha?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="loginbox-submit">
         <input type="hidden" name="enviar_cadastro" value="envia" />   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Entrar">
        </div>
    </div>
 
 
 </form>
    <div class="logobox">
 
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
string usuario = "admin";
        string senha = "admin";

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = "login=" + usuario;
        postData += ("senha=" + senha);
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/");
        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
        Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
        // Send the data.
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(newStream);
        newStream.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(reader.ToString());
```

Comment: O que é que tá acontecendo? Tá chegando no servidor no método de login?

Comment: Estou utilizando o código no evento do botão, mas simplesmente não acontece nada, já tentei como get(eu mudei o formulário também) mesmo assim não efetua login e não aparece nenhum erro.

Comment: Para em algum bp nesse método? Ele entra no método, é isso? Mas não chama o outro projeto que verifica o login?

Comment: Se eu executar ele linha por linha ele vai executar o form, mas quando clico no botão não acontece nada.
Eu quero que ao clicar ele entre no link e efetue o login e retorne se foi bem sucedido

Comment: Entre em qual link? Seu form não tem action. Qndo submita vai pra onde?

Comment: No link localhost, quando submita tem o codigo em php que verifica se o login está correto e se estiver ok, entra no localhost\dasboard.php

Comment: Tua pergunta não tá muito clara pra mim. Eu não to entendendo. Esse código que tu colocou em c# significa o q se ele submita pra uma página em php q não tá na action? =T

Comment: Eu atualizei o código do post